# May I ask how to repaint() repeatedly?

Tags: java, swing, paint, repaint, paintcomponent

Excuse me,May I ask java repaint repeatlyed questions,
I meet a trouble that I use drafting repeatedly  to express Pacman Open&Close mouth motion.
But this program Only once will not move...
Somebody can help me to solve this problem...
Very thanks so much!:D

My code as below:

```
package Strive;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class CDrawF extends JFrame {
    CDrawF (){
        setTitle("繪製各式圖形");                       //JFrame interface
        setBounds(50, 50, 490, 260);        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        for(int i = 0; i<= 360; i++){              //repeatly 360 times
        repaint();
        g2.setColor(new Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));               
        g2.fill(new Arc2D.Double(100, 100, 80, 80, 30, 300, Arc2D.PIE)); 
        //PacMan close mouth
        repaint();
        try{            //Delay setions
                Thread.sleep(1000);
             }catch(InterruptedException ex){}
        g2.fill(new Arc2D.Double(100, 100, 80, 80, 10, 340, Arc2D.PIE)); 
        //PacMan open mouth
        repaint();
        }
    }
}

public class NewClass {          //Main
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new CDrawF ();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pacman open/close mouth animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426693/pacman-open-close-mouth-animation)

Answer (score 9):

Suggestions:

- Don't draw directly in the JFrame
- Don't draw in the paint(...) method.
- Never call `Thread.sleep(...)` on the Swing event thread
- And especially don't call it in a `paint(...)` or `paintComponent(...)` method.
- Instead draw in a JPanel or JComponent's paintComponent(...) method
- Read the Java graphics tutorials as they will explain **all** of this.
- Don't call `repaint()` inside of paint(...) or paintComponent(...)
- Use a Swing Timer for your animation loop. Again the tutorials will help you do this.

Comment: And for example please check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9986368/522444), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4702819/522444), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12545773/522444).

Comment: +1 ... Lol I am fighting myself to not add more exmaples of my own :P

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: ah go ahead, why not?